# How to make this work with Chrome on MAC: using shortcut key to do CMDs in menu

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am new to MAC. Before this, PC user.
On PC, Chrome, I can do this:

1. Copy an url somewhere.
2. Go to Chrome, move mouse to the address bar.
3. Right click.
4. Press 'D' on keyboard.

Now chrome go to the url U Copied. My point is, we no need to Paste and hit enter key anymore. This is way faster and convenient. Not just 'Paste and go', also 'Paste and search' etc.

But, mac seems does not support this, any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I don't see any way to add the "D" shortcut to the "Paste and Go" contextual menu.
However, you should try [Alfred](https://cachefly.alfredapp.com/Alfred_3.7.1_946.dmg)

Once installed, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Then just paste your link and it will open:

[image: Go to page]

Or enter the terms you want to search:

[image: Googl search]

It's fast and convenient. (no need to right-click into the Chrome address bar)

Comment: The user asked for a solution within the chrome. Alfred is a whole new application that needs to be installed!

Comment: @VighneshPai Yes, but as I said, I don't know how to add a short key to this contextual menu in Chrome, so I suggested to look at Alfred because that's what I'm using, and as he's new to Mac, he might not know it. By the way, even if Alfred is a different application, it can interact with Chrome, which is why I posted this answer.

Comment: Thx for answering. But I'm not using Alfred. I am a developer who must use Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.2 and using Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

If I copy an URL then I'm getting an option as Paster and Go

If I copy some random text (not an URL) I'm getting an option as Paster and Search.

This is working out of the box. No need to do anything!!

Comment: I would be very glad if people leave a comment when they downvote something.

Comment: In the question is "using shortcut key". That means how to make the action by pressing a key, not by clicking in the context menu. By the way, @Redick is not responding to those workarounds.

Comment: Sorry for responding late. This answer is not what I want. Still no clue.

Comment: What is it that you are looking for? As per your question you do not see the Paste&GO option in chrome right?

Comment: No, the option does indeed in my context menu. But I want to tigger the 'Paste&Go' by press a key on keyboard instead of move the mouse and click on it. This is already achieved by default on Windows PC. But what about Mac. After those days past, I think it cannot be done. (Mac sucks... not just this, so many features are very convenient on PC, but Mac doesn't care users' thought or want.)

Comment: That's why PC's often get hacked :P